# CGAL Endpoint Vertices of 3D Polyhedron

Tags: cgal, edges

Is there any way to get the two endpoint vertices of an edge from a 3D Polyhedron?  I know I can iterate over halfedges, but I would rather iterate over every other halfedge because I only need the edge length along each side of a given facet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `eit` an `Edge_iterator`, you can access the source and target vertices using `eit->opposite()->vertex()`  and `eit->vertex()` respectively. If you want to access the point associated to a vertex, you can use the `point()` member function (that is `eit->vertex()->point()`).